# select non unique record based on a unique combination of 2 fields cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have many records in Cosmos DB container with the following structure (sample):

```json
{
    "id": "aaaa",
    "itemCode": "1234",
    "itemDesc": "TEST",
    "otherfileds": ""
}

{
    "id": "bbbb",
    "itemCode": "1234",
    "itemDesc": "TEST2",
    "otherfileds": ""
}

{
    "id": "cccc",
    "itemCode": "5678",
    "itemDesc": "HELLO",
    "otherfileds": ""
}

{
    "id": "dddd",
    "itemCode": "5678",
    "itemDesc": "HELLO",
    "otherfileds": ""
}

{
    "id": "eeee",
    "itemCode": "9012",
    "itemDesc": "WORLD",
    "otherfileds": ""
}

{
    "id": "ffff",
    "itemCode": "9012",
    "itemDesc": "WORLD",
    "otherfileds": ""
}
```

Now I want to select records from this where an item code have a non distinct item description. Based on the above example records, I would like to return item code 1234 since it has different values of item descriptions in other records.

```
{
    "id": "aaaa",
    "itemCode": "1234",
    "itemDesc": "TEST",
    "otherfileds": ""
}

{
    "id": "bbbb",
    "itemCode": "1234",
    "itemDesc": "TEST2",
    "otherfileds": ""
}
```

I have tried the below query, but realised, it will return the duplicate entries which has same item code and description only.

```
select count(1) from (select distinct value d.itemCode FROM (SELECT
    c.itemCode, c.itemDesc, COUNT(1) as dupcount
FROM
    c where c.itemCode<>null
GROUP BY
    c.itemCode, c.itemDesc) d where d.dupcount>1 )
```

But I need to find records where the same item code is having different item descriptions (the query above will return only records which has more than one occurrence of item code/descriptions, ie, item code 9012 and 5678)

### EDIT

I think i managed to form the query to filter these results by 2 sub queries (I think this could be improved though).

```
select e.itemCode from (select  d.itemCode, count(1) as dupcount FROM 
(SELECT
    c.itemCode, c.itemDesc
FROM
    c where c.itemCode<>null
GROUP BY
    c.itemCode, c.itemDesc) d group by d.itemCode )e where e.dupcount>1
```

Comment: I suggest editing to show the query you tried, along with the issue(s) you're having. Also: at the end, you're asking for an RDBMS solution, and that should not be part of this question (1: it has nothing to do with a document store such as Cosmos DB; and 2) it will be dependent on both the SQL database engine you're using *and* the schema you have). I removed that from your question, accordingly, as it makes this question very broad/open-ended (more than it already is, even focusing just on Cosmos DB)

Comment: I think i managed to form the query to filter these results by 2 sub queries.
`code`
select e.itemCode from (select  d.itemCode, count(1) as dupcount FROM 
(SELECT
    c.itemCode, c.itemDesc
FROM
    c where c.itemCode<>null
GROUP BY
    c.itemCode, c.itemDesc) d group by d.itemCode )e where e.dupcount>1
 `code`

Comment: Great - so you should post that as an answer, not as an edit to your question (solutions should not be edited into questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to form the query to filter these results by 2 sub-queries (I think this could be improved though).

```
select distinct e.itemCode from (select  d.itemCode, count(1) as dupcount FROM 
(SELECT
    c.itemCode, c.itemDesc
FROM
    c where c.itemCode<>null
GROUP BY
    c.itemCode, c.itemDesc) d group by d.itemCode )e where e.dupcount>1
```